# Problem with missing values in Geopandas, matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I want to make a cloropleth world map.
I have added a column to the dataframe world with a number of occurences for each country. I have a dictionary with the name of each country and the number of occurrences for each country in my own dataset. I have matched this dictionary by countryname to the world dataframe using this code:

```
 world_countries = world['name'].tolist()
 count_i = []
 for i in world_countries:
    if i in countries_i:
        count_i.append(countries_i[i])
    else:
        count_i.append(np.nan)

 count_u = []
 for i in world_countries:
    if i in countries_u:
        count_u.append(countries_u[i])
    else:
        count_u.append(np.nan)

 world['count_i'] = count_i
 world['count_u'] = count_u
```

This all works fine, such that I have added two new columns matched on country name, where any countries that have no occurences just have NaN.

Then I try to plot the map using the code:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
 divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
 cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.1)

 world.plot(column='count_u', 
           ax=ax, 
           legend=True,
           cax=cax,
           edgecolor='k',
           legend_kwds={'label':'Developing Countries',
                        'orientation':'vertical'},
           cmap='GnBu',
           figsize=(15, 10),
           missing_kwds={'color': 'lightgrey'})
```

However, missing_kwds keeps giving me an error, saying 'PatchCollection' object has no property 'missing_kwds'. I have just installes GeoPandas, so it should be the newest system that has 'missing_kwds' but it won't work for me. I have tried plotting a different column to see if there was a problem with that specific column, but that makes no difference. Without missing_kwds the code works, but plots all the countries that have NaN, such that I can't tell the difference between countries with fx 2 occurences and countries with 0, i.e. NaN. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely using an old version of GeoPandas. If you update to the recent (0.8.1), your code will work. `missing_kwds` is a recent addition, which does not work in old versions.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I just installed GeoPandas last week, but I have 0.6.1. How do you update Geopandas?

Comment: Depends if it is installed via `pip` or `conda`. Since you got 0.6.1 last week, I am not sure about the source, but that'll be a quick google to figure it out (e.g. how to update python package).

Comment: I used `pip` originally and now  used `pip install geopandas --upgrade` to upgrade to 0.8.1 - and it works now! Thank you :)

Comment: You can accept the answer to mark the question as resolved.